# Reaction of benzenediazonium chloride with potassium ferricyanide

Tags: organic-chemistry

[image]

I have gone through all my notes but could not find any reaction of benzenediazonium chloride with potassium ferricyanide. What are possible products?

Comment: Google is your friend, read about the Sandmeyer reaction.

Comment: @ron .. I could not get the exact reaction on google.. but now that you mentioned Sandmeyers reaction.. Is the final product CyanoBenzene?

Comment: yes, cyanobenzene or benzonitrile